# Element x, y, width, height translation to different dimensions

Tags: image, algorithm, math

My math must be very rusty. I have to come up with an algorithm that will take a known:

- x
- y
- width
- height

of elements in a document and translate them to the same area on a different hardware device. For example, The document is being created for print (let's assume 8.5"x11" letter size) and elements inside of this document will then be transferred to a proprietary e-reader.

Also, the known facts about the e-reader, the screen is 825x1200 pixels portrait. There are 150 pixels per inch.

I am given the source elements from the printed document in points (72 Postscript points per inch).

So far I have an algorithm that get's close, but it needs to be exact, and I have a feeling I need to incorporate aspect ratio into the picture. What I am doing now is:

```
x (in pixels) = ( x(in points)/width(of document in points) ) * width(of ereader in pixels)
```

etc.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, you can't get it exactly right, because you can't use fractions of a pixel.  The best you can do is round to the nearest pixel in each dimension.  How far off is your calculation currently?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to revert the order of your operations to reduce the effect of integer truncation, as follows:

```
x (in pixels) =  x(in points) * width(of ereader in pixels) / width(of document in points)
```

I don't think you have an aspect ratio problem, unless you forgot to mention that your e-reader device has non-square pixels. In that case you will have a different amount of pixels per inch horizontally and vertically on the device's screen, so you will use the horizontal ppi for x and the vertical ppi for y.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your coordinates are integer numbers, the formula `x/width` is truncating (integer division).  What you need is to perform the division/multiplication in floating point numbers, *then* truncate.  Something like

```
(int)(((double)x)/width1*width2)
```

should do the trick (using C-like conversion to `double` and `int`)